# ffmpeg image overlay doesn't execute on expected time

Tags: ffmpeg

My image overlay is not playing on the expected time. I have this image list called "Lista.txt" where I set the time of 15 seconds for each image:

```
file 'C:\Users\ricar\Desktop\Criar Video com Propaganda (ffmpeg)\propaganda\couve_.png'
duration 15
file 'C:\Users\ricar\Desktop\Criar Video com Propaganda (ffmpeg)\propaganda\IMG_.png'
duration 15
file 'C:\Users\ricar\Desktop\Criar Video com Propaganda (ffmpeg)\propaganda\Kitkat_.png'
duration 15
file 'C:\Users\ricar\Desktop\Criar Video com Propaganda (ffmpeg)\propaganda\paracetamol_.png'
duration 15
file 'C:\Users\ricar\Desktop\Criar Video com Propaganda (ffmpeg)\propaganda\relogio2_.png'
duration 15
file 'C:\Users\ricar\Desktop\Criar Video com Propaganda (ffmpeg)\propaganda\relogio3_.png'
duration 15
file 'C:\Users\ricar\Desktop\Criar Video com Propaganda (ffmpeg)\propaganda\ruffles_.png'
duration 15
file 'C:\Users\ricar\Desktop\Criar Video com Propaganda (ffmpeg)\propaganda\Skittles_.png'
duration 15
```

Next I use this command to concatenate and put the images as overlay over the video but all the images last less than 1 second (1 frame I guess) exept for the last image which is displayed until the end of the video

[video link](https://i.imgur.com/TUmJW7i.mp4)

[Images to overlay](https://onedrive.live.com/download?cid=8E0E12FBD10DA3C0&resid=8E0E12FBD10DA3C0%2140937&authkey=ALhvukpAVyPmvvY)

```
ffmpeg -r 23.98 -t 40 -i "input.mp4" -safe 0 -r 23.98 -f concat -i Lista.txt -filter_complex "[1]scale=(iw/4):-1,format=yuva420p[over];[main][over]overlay=x=W-w:y=H-h[Final]" -map [Final] -y -c:v libx264 "output.mp4"
```

Comment: The `duration` feature is not working with images. Test it without `overlay` fist: `ffmpeg -y -safe 0 -f concat -r 23.98 -i Lista.txt -c:v libx264 output.mp4`.

Comment: No, it plays superquick but if I remove -r 23.98 that part would be as intended, I think it get's messed when it get mixed with the video which has a framerate of 23.98...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use [fps filter](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/ChangingFrameRate) for `Lista.txt` input instead of `-r 23.98`:

`ffmpeg -r 23.98 -i "input.mp4" -safe 0 -f concat -i Lista.txt -filter_complex "[1]fps=23.98,scale=(iw/4):-1,format=yuva420p[over];[0:v][over]overlay=x=W-w:y=H-h[Final]" -map [Final] -y -c:v libx264 -t 40 "output.mp4"`

I tested the above command, and it seems to work as expected.

As you commented, it looks like the `-r 23.98` messes things up (I don't understand the reason).

---

### Update:

The above solution is not working with the latest version of FFmpeg.

Suggested alternative - use two stages:

- Encode the list of images to uncompressed AVI in RGBA pixel format.
- Overlay the AVI video over the input video.

Example:

`ffmpeg -y -f concat -safe 0 -i Lista.txt -vf "scale=(iw/4):-1,setsar=1" -c:v rawvideo -pix_fmt rgba images.avi`

`ffmpeg -r 23.98 -i input.mp4 -i images.avi -filter_complex "[1:v]fps=23.98[over];[0:v]format=rgba[main];[main][over]overlay=x=W-w:y=H-h[Final]" -map [Final] -y -c:v libx264 -crf 17 -t 40 output.mp4`

---

[image]

---

Update:

I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67531933/4926757):
We may add `-reinit_filter 0` argument.
It looks like the reason it wasn't working with your input images (but worked with my test images) is related to the fact the the images have different parameters.

The following command is working (in a single stage):

`ffmpeg -r 23.98 -i "input.mp4" -safe 0 -f concat -reinit_filter 0 -i Lista.txt -filter_complex "[1]fps=23.98,scale=(iw/4):-1,format=rgba[over];[0:v]format=rgba[main];[main][over]overlay=x=W-w:y=H-h[Final]" -map [Final] -y -c:v libx264 -t 40 "output.mp4"`

Comment: After changing form -r 23.98 to fps=23.98 the overlay doesn't show at all in the resulting video...

Comment: I tested using version 4.4.1 and version 5.1, and the overlay shows up. Note that I also replaced `[main]` with `[0:v]`. Another change is moving `-t 40` to the output arguments. Can you share one or two images?

Comment: No luck with version: 2022-02-24-git-8ef03c2ff1-full_build-www.gyan.dev. I added a link to the images I'm trying to overlay. I'll try to download a new version in case it is the ffmpeg version, thanks so far...

Comment: Now I have this version but still no luck: n5.1.1-20220904

Comment: You are right, the solution is not working with the latest version of FFmpeg. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time, I had this working before in a similar way (2-step-encoding) except that I used an animated PNG image instead of raw avi video. Why are there 2 overlay images shown at the same time in the in the screenshot you attached is that intended?

Comment: The smaller overlay image is part of the input video.

Comment: Ah right....all ok than, any reason to use rgba instead of yuva420p?

Comment: `yuva420p` applies chroma subsampling, and `rgba` isn't, so the quality may be a little better. I figured out the adding `-reinit_filter 0` solves the issue in a single stage (updated my answer again).

Comment: thank you, 100% satisfied with the answer now, maybe just change "yuv420p" with "rgba" for transparency, thank you very much.